# MacBook Pro: How to open last terminal tabs on restart?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

On my Macbook terminal I have 1 window opens with 4 tabs.

When I am restarting, it asks to 'Terminate processes' once I click & restart MacBook pro.

Terminal opens with Basic profile only.

How can I open my last windows 4 tabs again.

I can't find in preferences.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4GD3.png in General Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, so I will post an answer instead, though I don't expect it to solve your problem.

If you're asking for a one-time restore (like the "Recently closed tabs" option in Chrome), I don't know of any way to "restore" those specific tabs and commands. You can type `history` into the Terminal and it will list the last 500 commands issued, if you're just trying to remember the commands you entered previously.

Perhaps you could save your tabs as a Window Group before restarting your computer if this is something that happens on a regular basis. Do this by clicking on the Window menu, then clicking "Save Windows as Group..." and name the window group then select the "Restore all commands" option.

Answer (score 0):

"Save Window Group" is a feature you can find in the Terminal menu.

Comment: While this answer does technically address the question posited, having the key parts of summarized here.  Should the link go stale, at least the reader can still get they are interested in.   Oh, and welcome to Ask Different!